# Port 8082 can't be reached in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, firewall

I have a http application running on port 8082 in my Ubuntu environment. The machine is reachable via ping. Are there any ways of allowing specific ports Ubuntu, assuming firewall is turned off?

Comment: What is the output of `nmap -p 8028 <your ip here>`?

Comment: Host is up (0.000051s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8082/tcp closed blackice-alerts

Comment: All ports should be allowed if the firewall is truly turned off. Did you already do `sudo ufw disable`?

Comment: Yes. Output is:
`Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup`

Comment: 8080 and 8081 are `open` though, but not `8082`.

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -i :8082` run on the Ubuntu system you're trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8082 -j ACCEPT
 sudo ufw allow 8082
```